# dump-autoload command from php

Tags: php, linux, laravel-4, composer-php

I am building a web application where the user dynamically can upload Controllers php files from the web browser. There is a problem in all of this.

Since every class should be compiled in order be used inside of laravel, the commmand `composer dump-autoload`  must be executed. But I do not want to do this manually from the terminal. Inside of a "register class" I have called explicitly some commands that have not worked for me, for example:

- `Artisan::call('dump-autoload');`
- `exec("/path/to/app/composer dump-autoload");`
- `shell_exec('php artisan dump-autoload');`
- `shell_exec('composer dump-autoload');`

The new controllers are still not being found. So, I do not know what I am missing. Or if there is another way to "load" my classes dynamically.

#### Things to consider:

1. Security implications: of course, but my question is widely open to dynamically recognize new classes in execution time
2. I am completely sure about paths, I have tested every issue from a linux terminal and all worked fine (with absolute and relative path). For these reasons, I look for another reason instead of paths.
3. `Don't forget to actually 'require' or 'include' the class after you compile it` Sure, the file is included and confirmed by the point 2.
4. This looks suspicious:

   > my off-the-cuff guess would be that the user running php doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the operation or write to the required directories

   However, how could it be possible that php doesn't have enough privileges, could be it affects the `composer dump-autoclass` command?
5. Apache/2.4.9 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.12

Comment: You sure your composer know where to find those uploaded classes? Assuming you have added the folder to your composer classmap?

Comment: Yes, totally sure. Why? 1. Because the classes are dropped at /app/controllers folder. 2. Because if I execute `composer dump-autoload` from terminal directly, the classes are loaded as I expect inside of my app

Comment: "However, How could be possible that the fact php doesn't have enoght privileges, could be it affects the composer dump-autoclass command?" -- because if the process can't write the compiled file out to the directory, the result is as if you didn't run the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to work this out you can do this:

```
exec("composer dump-autoload -d /path/to/laravel-project/");
```

You have to explicitly tell composer where to look for `composer.json`.

`-d` If specified use the given directory as working directory

Without `-d` option, composer assumes your `composer.json` lives in `path/to/laravel-project/public/`. Because all requests are routed to front controller `index.php` and by that mean the current working directory is `public/`

Comment: Not working at least for me. I suspect that this problem could be a linux secury rule. I do not have another explanation

Comment: Try with `passthru` instead of `exec` and whats the output?

Comment: In a simple php with only this line the output is a string of zero lenght

Comment: `var_dump(passthru("composer dump-autoload -d /var/www/html/Laravel/"));`. Sorry, this returns a `null`

Comment: @manix If invalid directory path added it actually returns `NULL`  but if the path is valid I get `Generating autoload files`. Re-check your absolute directory path is it `Laravel` or `laravel`.

Comment: I know that the capital letter looks like a assassin, but the path is actually correct. Checked again and again

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really enough information here to help us help you.

Things to consider:

- just want to mention the horrible security implications
- I'm not going to address path issues, just be sure they're complete and absolute
- my off-the-cuff guess would be that the user running php doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform the operation or write to the required directories
- don't forget to actually 'require' or 'include' the class after you compile it
- make sure that your autoloader is actually firing, maybe with some logging or the like
- make sure you don't have php safe mode enabled, and that you move the uploaded file before doing any work on it

Try updating your question with some additional information if you can please.

Comment: I have updated the question. Let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it. What I did to solve this:

```
composer update
```

gave me the following error:

[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]

### "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
Parse error on line 9:
"require-dev

Expected: 'STRING' - It appears you have an extra trailing comma
I opened composer.json and there was one extra comma in last line:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.1.0",
    "laravel/framework": "9.1.*",
}
```

Removed the comma so it looked like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.1.0",
    "laravel/framework": "9.1.*"
}
```

And problem was gone.