# composer dump-autoload not working on controller Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I want run `php /bin/composer.phar dump-autoload` on my controller.
When I run `shell_exec("php /bin/composer.phar dump-autoload");`
 dose not work because when I run `shell_exec("dir");` I am on public folder and When I run this command `shell_exec("cd.. & php /bin/composer.phar dump-autoload");` Nothing not happen 
because when run `shell_exec("cd .. ; dir ")` I am on public folder yet.
My host in centos 6

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704140/dump-autoload-command-from-php) answer. I hope you will get some workaround.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238547/run-composer-dump-autoload-from-controller-in-laravel-5/65718344#65718344

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `\Symfony\Components\Process\Process`.

So you would have something like:

```
(new \Symfony\Components\Process\Process('composer dump-autoload', base_path()))->setTimeout(10)->mustRun();
```

Hope this helps!